# DB2 The data type for parameter or SQL Variable not supported

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I am using in my stored procedure a very long sql inside *EXECUTE IMMEDIATE*

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'sql statements'
```

The problem is when I reach some kind of of characters (approx. 4000) inside EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, I cannot save the stored procedure because I got an error like

```
{0:0} The data type for parameter or SQL variable (is not supported in the  routine, compound SQL statement, or parameter list of a cursor value constructor.. SQLCODE=-789, SQLSTATE=429BB, DRIVER=4.28.11
```

Will be their any character limitation?, when yes can we force to ignore?

DB2 Enterprise Server Edition: 11.1
DB2 v11.1.4.5, Fixpack 5

Comment: Ok I just updated the version, is it possible to change limitation?

Comment: `SQL789` is not a limitation, but erroneous statement. What does it mean "I cannot save the stored procedure"? Don't you able to create it or do you get this error from CALL using this routine? Try to, say, `DECLARE V_STMT CLOB (8K);` and use series of `SET V_STMT = V_STMT || 'some subsequent part of the whole statement';`. Use `EXECUTE V_STMT;` finally. Try to print out the final statement with, say, DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE routine to some file and execute the statement with db2 CLP.

Comment: Db2-LUW allows up to 2097152 bytes for the execute immediate, although in a CLOB host variable, not as a literal string.

Comment: I was not able to create a stored procedure, but with CLOB it is working.